# Disable actual call of method by aspects

Tags: java, aop

Is it possible to disable actuall method's call. What I would like to achieve is create aspect which will be called before my method and if some statement is true then not to call the main method at all.

Using pseudocode it would be something like this

```
public class MyClass {

  public void myMethod() {
     //implementation
  }
}

@Aspect
public class MyAspect {
  @Before("execution(* MyClass.myMethod(..))")
  public void doSth() {
    //do something here but if some statement is true then don't call myMethod
  }
}
```

Is it possible at all? Or maybe it is possible with something else not aspects?

Comment: What's wrong with just adding an `if` statement in your method block?

Comment: You can use `@Around` and joinpoint to achieve this

Comment: @RobertColumbia it's more like 'if possible' question. Just my curiosity.

Comment: @iNan damn you are right. Thanks :)

Comment: @iNan, how about writing an actual answer with some more code so as to enable the OP to accept and thus close the question? It is not nice to find the answer in a comment only. What you wrote is correct, but not enough for beginners to understand how to actually do it.

Comment: @kriegaex Thanks, I have written the actual answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `@Around` and `ProceedingJoinPoint` you should be able to do this. For example

```
  @Around("execution(* MyClass.myMethod())")
  public void doSth(ProceedingJoinPoint joinpoint) throws Throwable {

     boolean invokeMethod = false; //Should be result of some computation
     if(invokeMethod)
     {
         joinpoint.proceed();
     }
     else
     {
         System.out.println("My method was not invoked");
     }
  }
```

I have set `invokeMethod` boolean to false here, but it should be the result of some computation which you would do to determine whether you want to execute a method or not.  `joinPoint.proceed` does the actual invokation of the method.

Comment: do you know how to include this aspect in any other project? If I imported it as a maven dependency the aspect doesn't work (it only works in the project where it's implemented). I've added aspectj libs in my external project but it didn't change a thing.

Comment: @wawek, your question is totally unrelated to this one, you should not hijack it. If you want to know how to correctly use [AspectJ Maven Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/), please read the description and/or use the search here on SO, I have answered many questions about it.